# Use of the Phrase 'Home Tuition'

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Are the following sentences correct:

```
I am an English home tutor.
I give home tuition for English to students of classes up to 12th.
I offer English home tuition to housewives.
I provide home tuition in English for/to children under 10 years of age.
```

Comment: Is this a service you yourself are offering? The reason I ask is that all the sentences except the last one contain either errors or significant ambiguities that call the competence of the prospective teacher into question.

Comment: Yes. I teach spoken English. And we don't use AmE in India. We don't use 'tuition' in place of 'tuition fee'. Can you tell me what is wrong with these sentences and why?

Comment: What exactly troubles you? I think you need to ask a question more specific than "Is everything all right with all these things?"

Comment: Nothing troubles me. I wanted to know what I asked. If you've got the answer, please answer. If not, leave it.

Comment: Singh, AFAIK that isn't how ELU works.

Comment: Sorry, but I did not like the first part of your comment. What troubles you!

Answer (score 1):

```
I am an English home tutor.
    -I tutor in English at your home.
I give home tuition for English to students of classes up to 12th.
    -I tutor English students at home up to grade 12.
I offer English home tuition to housewives.
    -I offer tutoring in English to housewives.
I provide home tuition in English for/to children under 10 years of age.
    -I provide tutoring at home in English to children under 10 years of age.
```

I tried to keep your general style in the phrases, while also rewording them.  The sentences you wrote are not something you would see written in the United States.  The word *tuition* is used exclusively for the cost of school.  Even if your usage is technically correct, that usage is obscure and/or antiquated.  If a native English speaker (from the States) saw those sentences they would think you speak English poorly.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Are they confusing seen from the point of view of a speaker of British English? I want to draw your attention to the fact that in the UK 'tuition' usually doesn't mean 'tuition fees'; it usually means 'teaching or tutoring'.

Comment: I am a native speaker from the US so I can't speak for other varieties of English in regards to tuition, just that in the States, it is so rare it may not even be understood.  I would say that this line: 'of classes up to 12th' is very awkward for any variety.  I would say something like 'up to grade 12' or 'up to class 12' (with the former being more American, the latter possibly more British). I would not use 'for/to' two prepositions is unnecessary, 'to children' sounds most natural to me, but 'for children' is not wrong.

Comment: Ok. I meant to use only one preposition. I gave the second one as a possibility. I also used an oblique to show this.

Answer (score 0):

From the perspective of one in the US, yes, the sentences are technically correct. There may be some confusion in your audience, though, as "tuition" has more than one meaning, and the way you are using it in your last three sentences is not the most common. Besides meaning *teaching*, tuition also means a payment for teaching, and the usage as a payment is probably more widely recognized than the use as a synonym for teaching.

In those last three sentences, I would use the word "instruction" in place of tuition, not because tuition is technically wrong, but because it is more apt to be misunderstood.

The usage in other parts of the English speaking world may be different.

Comment: *Tuition* means 'the cost charged to a student for their education' in the USA, but not in the UK, where the usual term for this concept is 'fee(s)' or 'tuition fee(s)'. So your terminology will need to match the geography of your audience.

Comment: But I think 'instruction' doesn't collocate with 'home'. How does the phrase 'home instruction' sound in the context?

Comment: "Instruction" is an activity; "home" is a place. In the US, "home instruction", or more verbosely, "instruction in your home" would play quite nicely.

Comment: *Tutoring* is the most suitable choice in this context, *instruction* the least. *Tuition* would be somewhere in the middle.

Comment: *Home tuition* seems to be the most common phrase in BrE; *home instruction* in AmE. [See Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=home+instruction%3Aeng_gb_2012%2Chome+instruction%3Aeng_us_2012%2Chome+tuition%3Aeng_gb_2012%2Chome+tuition%3Aeng_us_2012%2Chome+tutoring+&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=7&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chome%20instruction%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chome%20instruction%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chome%20tuition%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chome%20tuition%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chome%20tutoring%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: In India, "tuition" remains the correct choice. It will be well-understood and other words will seem pretentious or awkward.